# Remove Firebase Token in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I successfully integrated firebase in my app.I try to receive push notification in project.I have one problem and I'll explain it.In my project I have custom sign in and log out pages.First time For example ,if logined  some user and server sent notification ,user can see it,but if user log outed  and another user has started to use app, notification also coming ,by the way another user has loggined.It's happen because firebase token is a same.What's a best practice to check firebase notification? My goal is to send notification only user witch loggined
Thanks everyone
P.s
I searched about this problem.In my option, in my logout method I must remove firebase token and in a sign in method I must send token to server.
Is a correct way ,or is a another simple solution ?

Comment: As you mentioned on login get Firebase token and send it to your server. After logout delete that token.

Comment: You should unsubscribe the topic on logout\

Comment: Depending on the level of security required you could also send a targetID on your payload and check it before show a notification.